# Auto disconnects from router!

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, router, connection

Hey there! Recently, the routers in my house have encountered a problem. For some reason, it seems to auto-kick, or auto disconnect those who use it after everything from 5 seconds after we've connected, up to a incredible 20 minutes without disconnects. I think the problem is that the router can not handle more than 1-2 people at a time, but I'm not sure. When we get disconnects from the router, all we need to do is to connect up again then it will work for 5 seconds + before another disconnect happens.

This is very, very annoying, especially if we play games like call of duty when the disconnects happen, but if we are fast enough to disconnect/connect again to the internet we will not get kicked.

Therefore, I wondered. Is there anyone who have encountered this problem/know what to do?
Or is there anybody, somebody who knows about a script, for example autohotkey, to quickly disconnect/connect again to the internet?
Thanks in advance, every answer is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Does every computer get disconnected at the same time? are these computers wireless or wired? have you verified the router is still connected to the modem after the computers are disconnected?

Comment: It sounds to me that the router is going bad.  How long ago did you purchase it?

Comment: Not every computer get disconnected at the same time, it just randomly happens to people connected. all our computers are wireless. the router is connected to the modem after disconnects.. There is one router downstairs, and one upstairs so we get signals from all around the house. The router upstairs was put there for a little more than one month ago, from what I've heard the internet was just fine before this was put up there (but the net wasn't available upstairs then), so I'm guessing the router upstairs screw around with the internet. it was also probably bought 1month+ ago

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the firmware is up to date on both of your routers.  Go to the manufacturers website and download the latest.  You can use the web interface of each router to upload the new firmware.  Also, try to make sure that your routers are on different wifi channels as this may cause interference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a dual-band router or a router that supports Wireless N? If so, see if you can broadcast your network on the 2.4 GHz and/or the 5 GHz band at the same time (you may need to use different names). 5GHz is not supported on older devices, so if you can broadcast on both.

Also changing the channel of your signal may help if there are many other networks near you. I think the recommended channels (for 2.4GHz)are 1, 6, and 11.

It may also be a good idea to make sure the channels and SSIDs are different between the one upstairs and the one downstairs. I've never had two wifi routers at the same time, but this sounds like it could be part of the problem.